# Importing a module in haskell makes the code not compile

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following haskell code for test. It compiles fine with `ghc` (version 8.0.2), and prints 20, as expected.

```hs
f x = x * 2

main = print $ f 10
```

But when I import `Char` module like this:

```hs
module Data.Char

f x = x * 2

main = print $ f 10
```

it gives me this error: `test.hs:3:1: error: parse error on input ‘f’`.

Does haskell change the environment when a module is imported? What is the difference and am I importing the module wrong?

Comment: `module` *defines* a module, and you are missing the `where` keyword, which produces the parse error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`module` does not import modules; `import` does:

```
import Data.Char
```